# Apache POI : how to manage getLastRowNum errors

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to work on an Excel file.
Most of the time it works fine, but sometimes, getLastRowNum() returns a wrong number which causes a null pointer Exception when I arrive at the end of the file.

I want to be sure everything works fine, even when there is something wrong with getLastRowNum().

```
for (int i = FIRST_ROW_TO_GET; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    row = sheet.getRow(i);
    System.out.println(row.getCell(9));
}
```

I tried to use a if row.equals(null) but it doesn't change anything.

Any idea of what I can do?

Answer (score 5):

You can't call row.equals(null) since row is null in this case. You can do the check this way:

```
for (int i = FIRST_ROW_TO_GET; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    row = sheet.getRow(i);
    if (row != null){
        System.out.println(row.getCell(9));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below method will give the accurate last row number in excel, ignoring the blank cells :

```
int getRowCount(String sheetName) {
    int number = 0; 
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
    if (index == -1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);             
        for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            if(sheet.getRow(i)==null) {
                sheet.shiftRows(i+1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), -1);
                i--;
            }
            number = sheet.getLastRowNum() ;        
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Very good work. Works and helps finally to get rid of these invisible blank cells.